# Row size too large (> 8126) can i just change InnoDB to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have this error:

> Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to `TEXT` or `BLOB` or using `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` may help. In current row format, `BLOB` prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

To solve this can i just change InnoDB to MyISAM?

Comment: Sounds like a schema issue. Large rows usually mean you're storing some data in a row with names like column1, column2... columnN that should be in a separate table.

Comment: You are right, I made mistakes but now when I change table I need change many functions and probably making new errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change limit for "Mysql Row size too large"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large)

Comment: I'm not DB owner and i don't have permission to changing settings. I can set tables options. When i select InnoDB  i can choosing beetwen  compact or redundant in ROW_FORMAT. Dynamic or compressed i have when i choosing MyISAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could switch to MyISAM.  But that is not necessarily a good idea:

- MyISAM does not support transactions
- MyISAM tables often need `REPAIR` after a crash

An InnoDB table can handle more than 8KB per row.  Apparently you ran into the problem by having a dozen or more TEXT/BLOB columns?  At most 767 bytes of a column is stored in the main part of the row; the rest is put in a separate block.

I think one `ROW_FORMAT` will put all of a big columns in a separate block, leaving behind only 20 bytes to point at it.

Another approach to wide rows is to do "vertical partitioning".  That is, build another table (or tables) with a matching `PRIMARY KEY` and some of the big columns.  It is especially handy to move sparsely populated column(s) to such a table, then have fewer rows in that table, and use `LEFT JOIN` to fetch the data.  Also, if you have some column(s) that you rarely need to `SELECT`, then those are good candidates to move -- no `JOIN` needed when you don't need those columns.