# ERROR: Row size too large (> 8126). SEQULIZE

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

i got error while  working with sequlize-cli, i executed the command

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

and it returned the following error

```
ERROR: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

i am working with xampp on mac osx(catalina)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row size too large (> 8126) can i just change InnoDB to MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534868/row-size-too-large-8126-can-i-just-change-innodb-to-myisam)

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev it worked with mysql, but how do i go about that with sequelize