# typo3 too many editor field - error when saving

Tags: sql, compression, typo3

I have an extension (extbase) with many rte-editor fields (12). If I put some content in all editor field and click save, following error is shown:

> 2: SQL error: 'Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to
>   TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may
>   help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored
>   inline.' (tx_mwxx_domain_model_grundriss:2)

How can I solve this problem - `innodb_log_file_size` and `innodb_log_buffer_size` are big enough. Thanks for help!

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear.  You want to change some data types from `varchar()` (presumably) to `TEXT` or `BLOB` so each record fits in the available storage.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you make that an answer please? :-)

Comment: Hm ... I am not shure ... table has textgrundriss text NOT NULL and data is text. hier some more error message from bug-tracker:  lastBuiltQuery => 'UPDATE tx_mwxx_domain_model_grundriss SET textgrundriss=
      '<h2>xxxx</h2>\r\n<table border=\"0\" cel
      lpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\"
      ;> <tbody><tr> <td align=\"lef
      t\" valign=\"top\"><p class=\"bodytext\">N
      utzfläche:....,tstamp='1474206019',t3ver_stage='0' WHERE u
      id=2' (1044 chars)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change limit for "Mysql Row size too large"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is more simple. just add  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC when creating table:

CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
..
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

or if table exists:

ALTER TABLE `tablename` ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

BUT phpmyadmin can not do this (alter ...) - so I used a simple php script to alter the table.

Answer (score 0):

My provider solved problem by changing tables to Barracuda File Format. He also sent me following link with more informations: https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/