# Error when adding a column in database

Tags: mysql, blob, mariadb

I have a table with a longblob where I am storing documents inside. Since my hoster changed MySql to MariaDB Version 10.0.27 I got problems with loading data into the blob greater than 5 MB. Then I wanted to add a new column to the database to handle this programmatically by storing bigger files into the file system. But when adding the new column I get the following error:

> Error 1030: Got error 66 "Object is remote" from storage engine InnoDB
>   SQL Code:
>           ALTER TABLE `asbest`.`dokumente` 
>           ADD COLUMN `extfile` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Die Datei ist extern gespeichert (uber 5 MB) im Verteichnis /doks' AFTER `size`

I found on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large) that a Bug in MySql and MariaDB causes several problems related to blobs with large data.

Is this behaviour related th this? Could it be solved by changing the Storage Engine to Barracuda?

Comment: What is the value of `max_allowed_packet`?

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE dokumente`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I dont see it was answered. When I ran into this issue, my OS was CentOS 7. Per the mysql documentation found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-error-reference.html

*Error number: 1030; Symbol: ER_GET_ERRNO; SQLSTATE: HY000
Message: Got error %d from storage engine
Check the %d value to see what the OS error means. For example, 28 indicates that you have run out of disk space*.

The key word here is, **"OS error"**.

For my situation, increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size (higher than 300M and up to 1G) and adjusting the innodb_log_file_size (log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size) in the "my.cnf" file fixed my issue.