# Why some photos can't upload in database?

Tags: php, mysql

In my application , am storing images files as blob in database. I considered letting php to process multiple image upload.

The script seems to work great but I realize some images files could not be stored in database so I change the type of table image column from **blob** to **longblob** and this time some of those photos which couldn't be uploaded are now uploaded correctly.

again, I realized still some image files could still not be stored in database.
I have spent time to read about blob data type and its just the length it varies.

**after a long debugging** what was wrong I got this message from server:

The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.

Please what could be the problem in my script or database?

below is my PHP code and  Table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `images`
--

CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` longblob NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


    <?php


if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){


        //Handle file upload and status as files description

        //lenght of files
        $files  = array();

        //dataArray
        $dataArray  = array();

        //loop through global FILES variable 
        foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $value){

            $files[] = $value;


            $filename   = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $filesize   = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
            $filetemp   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $fileerror  = $_FILES['file']['error'][$key];
            $file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.',$filename)));
            $valid_ext  = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');
            $maxsize    = 4 *1024 *1024;

            //get file MIME type
            $valid_mime = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/jpg','image/gif');
            $mime       = getimagesize($filetemp);
            $mime       = $mime['mime'];


            if($filesize > $maxsize || !in_array($file_ext,$valid_ext) || !in_array($mime,$valid_mime) ){
            //tell the user we can't upload files

            $template = "<div class='overlay'></div>
            <div class='er_cnt'>
            <span class='er_cnt_span'>Can't Read Files</span>
            <p> Your photo: <strong>$filename</strong> is not  valid. Photos should be less than 4 MB and saved as JPG, PNG or GIF files. </p>
            <br><hr><button class='close'> Close </button>
            </div>";

            echo $template;
            exit();

            }else{

            //*********Everything is okay so continue*******//

            //resize image...
            //read entire file into a string
            $data   =   file_get_contents($filetemp);


            //append data to the dataArray variable
            $dataArray[] = $data ;
            }


        } //end of first foreach



        //store image in database after foreach loop
        if(count($files) == count($dataArray) ){

        //get the length of dataArray
        $lenght     = count($dataArray);

        //define array to store image id
        $fileID = array();


        //grab the status coming from text area (use as file description)
        //first insert post description into database

        $status     = trim($_POST['status']); 
        $status     = htmlspecialchars($status);

        //prepare and bind statement
                    $sql    = $dbc_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                    $public_feed_table(user_id,post,timepost,file) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
                    $sql->bind_param('issi',$IsLoggIn,$status,$time_post, $image=1);


                    //execute 
                    $sql->execute();
                    //get the last insert id 
                    $post_id        =    $sql->insert_id;







            //loop through the dataArray
            for($i=0; $i < $lenght; $i++){

            //grab data from the array
            $file_content   =   mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc_conn,$dataArray[$i]);
            $mime           =   getimagesizefromstring($dataArray[$i]);
            $mime           =   $mime['mime'];


            //save file into database (images table)
            $sql    =   "INSERT INTO $images_table(image,user_id,post_id,mime_type)
             VALUES('$file_content','$IsLoggIn','$post_id','$mime')";


            $query  = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,$sql);

            //append  file id
            $fileID[]   = mysqli_insert_id($dbc_conn); 


        }


        }//end of array equallity







        //store data for use of JSON

            $username       =    getuser($IsLoggIn,'username');
            $post           =    $status;
            $datapost       =    $date_post;
            $total_rating   =    '0';
            $rating_msg     =    'Be the first to rate your tagline';
            $post_id        =    $post_id;
            $post_owner     =    $IsLoggIn;
            $name           =    ucfirst(getuser($IsLoggIn,'firstname'))." ".ucfirst(getuser($IsLoggIn,'lastname'));
            $rate_button    =    true;
            $voters_array   =    array();
            $account_dir    =    getuser($IsLoggIn,'directory');
            $avatar         =    getuser($IsLoggIn,'avatar');
            $file           =    1;
            $pp_id          =   fetch_pp($IsLoggIn);





        //send JSON as server response
        $ajax_data  =   array(
                        "u"         =>  $username,
                        "uid"       =>  $IsLoggIn,
                        "date"      =>  $date_post,
                        "pid"       =>  ''.$post_id.'',
                        "n"         =>  $name,
                        "f"         =>  $file,
                        "ppid"      =>  $pp_id,
                        "imageLength"   =>  $lenght,
                        "fid"           =>  implode(",",$fileID)

                        );
        // retruring data as JSON encode then we use client side to process the data
        echo json_encode($ajax_data);

    }
```

Comment: Storing images as *blob* in the database is not a great idea. Instead, store the images in your server and save the images' path in the database.

Comment: Is Facebook not photos in database?

Comment: look at this link: https://web.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1152869571466624&set=pcb.1152870088133239&type=3&theater

Comment: This is a good read on how Facebook manages to store and process billions of photos, [https://code.facebook.com/posts/685565858139515/needle-in-a-haystack-efficient-storage-of-billions-of-photos/](https://code.facebook.com/posts/685565858139515/needle-in-a-haystack-efficient-storage-of-billions-of-photos/)

Comment: after debuging I got this error: The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, storing files over ca. 100k as blobs in the database is bad practice. Store the path instead, and keep your files on the file server

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem from this answer: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large)

If you are running MySQL version 5.6.20 there is a known bug in the system. See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)