# Row size too large after I use Barracuda as file format in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have met similar situation like [change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large) said. I try to change the file format and I can get the table like below:

mysql> show variables like 'innodb%format%';

+---------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name             | Value     |
+---------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_default_row_format | dynamic   |
| innodb_file_format        | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_format_check  | ON        |
| innodb_file_format_max    | Barracuda |
+---------------------------+-----------+

However I also get the error said`Error Code: 1118. Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs`