# Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, codeigniter

Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

The above scenario exists when the following requirements are met.

1.I have a form submit page. In that page, we have an option to add a lot of columns to feed more data.

1. We have 4 Tabs in that page.
2. The first tab has 2cols x 9rows =18 textbox . and can further be added by clicking "Add column" so relatively we can add columns.
3. Similarly, we have the same set of rows and cols as the previous tab in the second tab.
4. The third tab has 4 static textboxes.
5. The fourth tab has 4rows x 2cols =8 textboxes and furthermore, columns can be added by clicking add a column.
6. So on an avg without any add columns, it is like 48 textboxes.But when we do add more dynamic columns which is like >60 to 120 textboxes and fully crowded with max characters.I'm facing row size too large error.

The data which im posting upon from submit are converted into json encode and is stored. it works good if i populate with less data but it throws up an sql query error upon crowding up with the maxium characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change limit for "Mysql Row size too large"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large)

Comment: But that didn't solve my problem.