# Can not change the data type of the field

Tags: sql, mysql

For table `email_fier` I try to change the type of field:

```
ALTER TABLE email_verifiers MODIFY COLUMN name text
```

I am getting this error:

> #1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.

I also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE email_verifiers MODIFY COLUMN name text(6000)
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE email_verifiers`.  We need ti see [at least] datatypes and indexes and engine in order to point out what caused the problem in your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large

Comment: We still hope you will post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE email_verifiers;  When time permits for analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
USE db_name;
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

but U gonna loose all advantages InnoDB has compared to MyISAM . MyISAM is maybe faster like transactions and constrains.

also
[According to mysql document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)
can  change my.cnf and set :

```
  innodb_log_file_size = 256M
```

Comment: if it doesnt work, instead consider splitting the data into multiple columns, or just use varchar if you can

Answer (score 1):

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format='dynamic';
SET SESSION innodb_strict_mode=OFF;
ALTER TABLE tab ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```