# ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 31: Row size too large

Tags: mysql, import

I have a huge data table - with hounderns columns.

I did a regular export and now I have problems with the import, i'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 31: Row size too large (> 8126).

Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline

I tried to changes tho following params (and it didn't solved the problem):

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_log_buffer_size to higer value
innodb_log_file_size to higer value
innodb_default_row_format = COMPACT OR innodb_default_row_format = DYNAMIC
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.33 and can't downgrade to 5.5.x version

What can I do to solve this problem?

Table columns:

```
CUST_ID bigint(20) 
OBJ_ID bigint(20) PK 
OBJ_DEF_ID bigint(20) 
PROCESS_ID bigint(20) 
STATUS_ID bigint(20) 
OBJ_NAME varchar(200) 
LOCATION_ID bigint(20) 
DEPARTMENT_ID bigint(20) 
FUNCTION_ID bigint(20) 
ORIGINAL_ID char(22) 
STR0 varchar(100) 
STR1 varchar(100) 
STR2 varchar(100) 
STR3 varchar(100) 
STR4 varchar(100) 
STR5 varchar(100) 
STR6 varchar(100) 
STR7 varchar(100) 
STR8 varchar(100) 
STR9 varchar(100) 
STR10 varchar(100) 
STR11 varchar(100) 
STR12 varchar(100) 
STR13 varchar(100) 
STR14 varchar(100) 
STR15 varchar(100) 
STR16 varchar(100) 
STR17 varchar(100) 
STR18 varchar(100) 
STR19 varchar(100) 
STR20 varchar(100) 
STR21 varchar(100) 
STR22 varchar(100) 
STR23 varchar(100) 
STR24 varchar(100) 
STR25 varchar(100) 
STR26 varchar(100) 
STR27 varchar(100) 
STR28 varchar(100) 
STR29 varchar(100) 
STR30 varchar(100) 
STR31 varchar(100) 
STR32 varchar(100) 
STR33 varchar(100) 
STR34 varchar(100) 
STR35 varchar(100) 
STR36 varchar(100) 
STR37 varchar(100) 
STR38 varchar(100) 
STR39 varchar(100) 
STR40 varchar(100) 
STR41 varchar(100) 
STR42 varchar(100) 
STR43 varchar(100) 
STR44 varchar(100) 
STR45 varchar(100) 
STR46 varchar(100) 
STR47 varchar(100) 
STR48 varchar(100) 
STR49 varchar(100) 
STR50 varchar(100) 
STR51 varchar(100) 
STR52 varchar(100) 
STR53 varchar(100) 
STR54 varchar(100) 
STR55 varchar(100) 
STR56 varchar(100) 
STR57 varchar(100) 
STR58 varchar(100) 
STR59 varchar(100) 
STR60 varchar(100) 
STR61 varchar(100) 
STR62 varchar(100) 
STR63 varchar(100) 
STR64 varchar(100) 
STR65 varchar(100) 
STR66 varchar(100) 
STR67 varchar(100) 
STR68 varchar(100) 
STR69 varchar(100) 
STR70 varchar(100) 
STR71 varchar(100) 
STR72 varchar(100) 
STR73 varchar(100) 
STR74 varchar(100) 
STR75 varchar(100) 
STR76 varchar(100) 
STR77 varchar(100) 
STR78 varchar(100) 
STR79 varchar(100) 
STR80 varchar(100) 
STR81 varchar(100) 
STR82 varchar(100) 
STR83 varchar(100) 
STR84 varchar(100) 
STR85 varchar(100) 
STR86 varchar(100) 
STR87 varchar(100) 
STR88 varchar(100) 
STR89 varchar(100) 
STR90 varchar(100) 
STR91 varchar(100) 
STR92 varchar(100) 
STR93 varchar(100) 
STR94 varchar(100) 
STR95 varchar(100) 
STR96 varchar(100) 
STR97 varchar(100) 
STR98 varchar(100) 
STR99 varchar(100) 
STR100 varchar(100) 
STR101 varchar(100) 
STR102 varchar(100) 
STR103 varchar(100) 
STR104 varchar(100) 
STR105 varchar(100) 
STR106 varchar(100) 
STR107 varchar(100) 
STR108 varchar(100) 
STR109 varchar(100) 
STR110 varchar(100) 
STR111 varchar(100) 
STR112 varchar(100) 
STR113 varchar(100) 
STR114 varchar(100) 
STR115 varchar(100) 
STR116 varchar(100) 
STR117 varchar(100) 
STR118 varchar(100) 
STR119 varchar(100) 
STR120 varchar(100) 
STR121 varchar(100) 
STR122 varchar(100) 
STR123 varchar(100) 
STR124 varchar(100) 
STR125 varchar(100) 
STR126 varchar(100) 
STR127 varchar(100) 
STR128 varchar(100) 
STR129 varchar(100) 
STR130 varchar(100) 
STR131 varchar(100) 
STR132 varchar(100) 
STR133 varchar(100) 
STR134 varchar(100) 
STR135 varchar(100) 
STR136 varchar(100) 
STR137 varchar(100) 
STR138 varchar(100) 
STR139 varchar(100) 
STR140 varchar(100) 
STR141 varchar(100) 
STR142 varchar(100) 
STR143 varchar(100) 
STR144 varchar(100) 
STR145 varchar(100) 
STR146 varchar(100) 
STR147 varchar(100) 
STR148 varchar(100) 
STR149 varchar(100) 
STR150 varchar(100) 
STR151 varchar(100) 
STR152 varchar(100) 
STR153 varchar(100) 
STR154 varchar(100) 
STR155 varchar(100) 
STR156 varchar(100) 
STR157 varchar(100) 
STR158 varchar(100) 
STR159 varchar(100) 
STR160 varchar(100) 
STR161 varchar(100) 
STR162 varchar(100) 
STR163 varchar(100) 
STR164 varchar(100) 
STR165 varchar(100) 
STR166 varchar(100) 
STR167 varchar(100) 
STR168 varchar(100) 
STR169 varchar(100) 
STR170 varchar(100) 
STR171 varchar(100) 
STR172 varchar(100) 
STR173 varchar(100) 
STR174 varchar(100) 
STR175 varchar(100) 
STR176 varchar(100) 
STR177 varchar(100) 
STR178 varchar(100) 
STR179 varchar(100) 
STR180 varchar(100) 
STR181 varchar(100) 
STR182 varchar(100) 
STR183 varchar(100) 
STR184 varchar(100) 
STR185 varchar(100) 
STR186 varchar(100) 
STR187 varchar(100) 
STR188 varchar(100) 
STR189 varchar(100) 
STR190 varchar(100) 
STR191 varchar(100) 
STR192 varchar(100) 
STR193 varchar(100) 
STR194 varchar(100) 
STR195 varchar(100) 
STR196 varchar(100) 
STR197 varchar(100) 
STR198 varchar(100) 
STR199 varchar(100) 
INTG0 bigint(20) 
INTG1 bigint(20) 
INTG2 bigint(20) 
INTG3 bigint(20) 
INTG4 bigint(20) 
INTG5 bigint(20) 
INTG6 bigint(20) 
INTG7 bigint(20) 
INTG8 bigint(20) 
INTG9 bigint(20) 
INTG10 bigint(20) 
INTG11 bigint(20) 
INTG12 bigint(20) 
INTG13 bigint(20) 
INTG14 bigint(20) 
INTG15 bigint(20) 
INTG16 bigint(20) 
INTG17 bigint(20) 
INTG18 bigint(20) 
INTG19 bigint(20) 
INTG20 bigint(20) 
INTG21 bigint(20) 
INTG22 bigint(20) 
INTG23 bigint(20) 
INTG24 bigint(20) 
INTG25 bigint(20) 
INTG26 bigint(20) 
INTG27 bigint(20) 
INTG28 bigint(20) 
INTG29 bigint(20) 
INTG30 bigint(20) 
INTG31 bigint(20) 
INTG32 bigint(20) 
INTG33 bigint(20) 
INTG34 bigint(20) 
INTG35 bigint(20) 
INTG36 bigint(20) 
INTG37 bigint(20) 
INTG38 bigint(20) 
INTG39 bigint(20) 
INTG40 bigint(20) 
INTG41 bigint(20) 
INTG42 bigint(20) 
INTG43 bigint(20) 
INTG44 bigint(20) 
INTG45 bigint(20) 
INTG46 bigint(20) 
INTG47 bigint(20) 
INTG48 bigint(20) 
INTG49 bigint(20) 
INTG50 bigint(20) 
INTG51 bigint(20) 
INTG52 bigint(20) 
INTG53 bigint(20) 
INTG54 bigint(20) 
INTG55 bigint(20) 
INTG56 bigint(20) 
INTG57 bigint(20) 
INTG58 bigint(20) 
INTG59 bigint(20) 
INTG60 bigint(20) 
INTG61 bigint(20) 
INTG62 bigint(20) 
INTG63 bigint(20) 
INTG64 bigint(20) 
INTG65 bigint(20) 
INTG66 bigint(20) 
INTG67 bigint(20) 
INTG68 bigint(20) 
INTG69 bigint(20) 
INTG70 bigint(20) 
INTG71 bigint(20) 
INTG72 bigint(20) 
INTG73 bigint(20) 
INTG74 bigint(20) 
INTG75 bigint(20) 
INTG76 bigint(20) 
INTG77 bigint(20) 
INTG78 bigint(20) 
INTG79 bigint(20) 
INTG80 bigint(20) 
INTG81 bigint(20) 
INTG82 bigint(20) 
INTG83 bigint(20) 
INTG84 bigint(20) 
INTG85 bigint(20) 
INTG86 bigint(20) 
INTG87 bigint(20) 
INTG88 bigint(20) 
INTG89 bigint(20) 
INTG90 bigint(20) 
INTG91 bigint(20) 
INTG92 bigint(20) 
INTG93 bigint(20) 
INTG94 bigint(20) 
INTG95 bigint(20) 
INTG96 bigint(20) 
INTG97 bigint(20) 
INTG98 bigint(20) 
INTG99 bigint(20) 
INTG100 bigint(20) 
INTG101 bigint(20) 
INTG102 bigint(20) 
INTG103 bigint(20) 
INTG104 bigint(20) 
INTG105 bigint(20) 
INTG106 bigint(20) 
INTG107 bigint(20) 
INTG108 bigint(20) 
INTG109 bigint(20) 
INTG110 bigint(20) 
INTG111 bigint(20) 
INTG112 bigint(20) 
INTG113 bigint(20) 
INTG114 bigint(20) 
INTG115 bigint(20) 
INTG116 bigint(20) 
INTG117 bigint(20) 
INTG118 bigint(20) 
INTG119 bigint(20) 
INTG120 bigint(20) 
INTG121 bigint(20) 
INTG122 bigint(20) 
INTG123 bigint(20) 
INTG124 bigint(20) 
INTG125 bigint(20) 
INTG126 bigint(20) 
INTG127 bigint(20) 
INTG128 bigint(20) 
INTG129 bigint(20) 
INTG130 bigint(20) 
INTG131 bigint(20) 
INTG132 bigint(20) 
INTG133 bigint(20) 
INTG134 bigint(20) 
INTG135 bigint(20) 
INTG136 bigint(20) 
INTG137 bigint(20) 
INTG138 bigint(20) 
INTG139 bigint(20) 
INTG140 bigint(20) 
INTG141 bigint(20) 
INTG142 bigint(20) 
INTG143 bigint(20) 
INTG144 bigint(20) 
INTG145 bigint(20) 
INTG146 bigint(20) 
INTG147 bigint(20) 
INTG148 bigint(20) 
INTG149 bigint(20) 
DBL0 decimal(20,8) 
DBL1 decimal(20,8) 
DBL2 decimal(20,8) 
DBL3 decimal(20,8) 
DBL4 decimal(20,8) 
DBL5 decimal(20,8) 
DBL6 decimal(20,8) 
DBL7 decimal(20,8) 
DBL8 decimal(20,8) 
DBL9 decimal(20,8) 
DBL10 decimal(20,8) 
DBL11 decimal(20,8) 
DBL12 decimal(20,8) 
DBL13 decimal(20,8) 
DBL14 decimal(20,8) 
DBL15 decimal(20,8) 
DBL16 decimal(20,8) 
DBL17 decimal(20,8) 
DBL18 decimal(20,8) 
DBL19 decimal(20,8) 
DBL20 decimal(20,8) 
DBL21 decimal(20,8) 
DBL22 decimal(20,8) 
DBL23 decimal(20,8) 
DBL24 decimal(20,8) 
DBL25 decimal(20,8) 
DBL26 decimal(20,8) 
DBL27 decimal(20,8) 
DBL28 decimal(20,8) 
DBL29 decimal(20,8) 
DBL30 decimal(20,8) 
DBL31 decimal(20,8) 
DBL32 decimal(20,8) 
DBL33 decimal(20,8) 
DBL34 decimal(20,8) 
DBL35 decimal(20,8) 
DBL36 decimal(20,8) 
DBL37 decimal(20,8) 
DBL38 decimal(20,8) 
DBL39 decimal(20,8) 
DBL40 decimal(20,8) 
DBL41 decimal(20,8) 
DBL42 decimal(20,8) 
DBL43 decimal(20,8) 
DBL44 decimal(20,8) 
DBL45 decimal(20,8) 
DBL46 decimal(20,8) 
DBL47 decimal(20,8) 
DBL48 decimal(20,8) 
DBL49 decimal(20,8) 
TXT0 longtext 
TXT1 longtext 
TXT2 longtext 
TXT3 longtext 
TXT4 longtext 
TXT5 longtext 
TXT6 longtext 
TXT7 longtext 
TXT8 longtext 
TXT9 longtext 
TXT10 longtext 
TXT11 longtext 
TXT12 longtext 
TXT13 longtext 
TXT14 longtext 
TXT15 longtext 
TXT16 longtext 
TXT17 longtext 
TXT18 longtext 
TXT19 longtext 
TXT20 longtext 
TXT21 longtext 
TXT22 longtext 
TXT23 longtext 
TXT24 longtext 
TXT25 longtext 
TXT26 longtext 
TXT27 longtext 
TXT28 longtext 
TXT29 longtext 
TXT30 longtext 
TXT31 longtext 
TXT32 longtext 
TXT33 longtext 
TXT34 longtext 
TXT35 longtext 
TXT36 longtext 
TXT37 longtext 
TXT38 longtext 
TXT39 longtext 
TXT40 longtext 
TXT41 longtext 
TXT42 longtext 
TXT43 longtext 
TXT44 longtext 
TXT45 longtext 
TXT46 longtext 
TXT47 longtext 
TXT48 longtext 
TXT49 longtext 
DATE0 datetime 
DATE1 datetime 
DATE2 datetime 
DATE3 datetime 
DATE4 datetime 
DATE5 datetime 
DATE6 datetime 
DATE7 datetime 
DATE8 datetime 
DATE9 datetime 
DATE10 datetime 
DATE11 datetime 
DATE12 datetime 
DATE13 datetime 
DATE14 datetime 
DATE15 datetime 
DATE16 datetime 
DATE17 datetime 
DATE18 datetime 
DATE19 datetime 
DATE20 datetime 
DATE21 datetime 
DATE22 datetime 
DATE23 datetime 
DATE24 datetime 
DATE25 datetime 
DATE26 datetime 
DATE27 datetime 
DATE28 datetime 
DATE29 datetime 
DATE30 datetime 
DATE31 datetime 
DATE32 datetime 
DATE33 datetime 
DATE34 datetime 
DATE35 datetime 
DATE36 datetime 
DATE37 datetime 
DATE38 datetime 
DATE39 datetime 
DATE40 datetime 
DATE41 datetime 
DATE42 datetime 
DATE43 datetime 
DATE44 datetime 
DATE45 datetime 
DATE46 datetime 
DATE47 datetime 
DATE48 datetime 
DATE49 datetime 
EVENT_DATE datetime 
CREATED_BY bigint(20) 
CREATED_AT datetime 
UPDATED_BY bigint(20) 
UPDATED_AT datetime
```

Comment: This table structure is … suboptimal. That said, [this answer from a few years back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585700/14952832) might help … 

Comment: Vertical sharding may be an option. Also think about combining a lot of columns into one JSON column (applicability depends on the operations performed on the values).